# On each change check the objects if they have changes in React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to do something more advanced where I check for and set of old objects with new set of object arrays, and then put the ids that have change to the state.

So for example here is my code:

```
 const [skillsSets, setSkillSets] = useState({...allSkills})
 const [idOfChangedItem, setIdOfChangedItem] = useState([])
 
 useEffect(() => {
   skillsSets.map(skillSet = > {
   if(checkForChange(skillSet, oldSkillObject) === true){
    const newChanges = [...idOfChangedItems];
    newChanges.push(skillSet.id);
    }
    
  })
 }, [skillsSet])
```

Comment: You need to add this line `setIdOfChangedItem(newChanges);` after `newChanges.push(skillSet.id);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to had the setState that you create:

```
const [skillsSets, setSkillSets] = useState({...allSkills})
     const [idOfChangedItem, setIdOfChangedItem] = useState([])
     
     useEffect(() => {
       skillsSets.map(skillSet = > {
       if(checkForChange(skillSet, oldSkillObject) === true){
        const newChanges = [...idOfChangedItems];
        newChanges.push(skillSet.id);
        setIdOfChangedItem(newChanges);
        }
        
      })
     }, [skillsSet])
```